# How to plot only a subset of GNUPLOT's splot result?

Tags: 3d, gnuplot

I am using GNUPLOT's splot function to display a value of two independent variables. However, much of the data, a) I am not interested in, and b) I would eventually like to remove the "set view map" and see only the parts of the data that I am interested in as a 3D projection. At the moment, there is too much of a surface to really see the parts of the plot I want, they fall within a basin.

I would like to only display the data along the x = y, with probably a variance of a single unit in either direction, so more of a band of data rather than only data that falls on a straight line. It would start around (0,0) and finish near (6,6).

My rudimentary GNU code is:

```
set palette rgbformulae 30,31,32
set size square
set view map
splot 'free_energy.dat' using 1:2:3 with pm3d
```

Unfortunately, I don't have the 10 reputation points yet to post images so here is the link to the splot image:

https://i1.wp.com/distributedscience.files.wordpress.com/2018/01/screen-shot-2018-01-05-at-06-44-59.png?ssl=1&w=450

The data file is pretty huge, hence I am quite reluctant to parse or delete the data itself. A very minimal example of the columns can be seen below. I am only interested in d.y (x), dRMSD (y), and file.free (dependent variable).

```
#! FIELDS d.y dRMSD file.free der_d.y der_dRMSD
#! SET min_d.y -8.01552
#! SET max_d.y 7.99331
#! SET nbins_d.y  92
#! SET periodic_d.y false
#! SET min_dRMSD -1.69088
#! SET max_dRMSD 12.5407
#! SET nbins_dRMSD  82
#! SET periodic_dRMSD false
-8.015520000   -1.690880000 1588.947840498   -0.000000000   -0.000000000
-7.839598791   -1.690880000 1588.947840498   -0.000000000   -0.000000000-
-7.663677582   -1.690880000 1588.947840498   -0.000000000   -0.000000000
```

Comment: `set xrange` and `set yrange`

Comment: Is this possible along a diagonal?  set xrange [0:6], set yrange [0:6] would still give me quite a large area of data.

Answer (score 1):

Try a conditional statement like:

```
splot 'free_energy.dat' using 1:2:(($1<$2)?3:1/0) with pm3d
```

which makes a cut along the x=y line. Later you can vary it eg.:

```
splot 'free_energy.dat' using 1:2:(($1>0.9*$2 && $1<1.1*$2)?3:1/0) with pm3d
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Happy to vote you up when I've got the reputation to do so.